# How to use name of mediaElement created by code and using its name in another method?

Tags: c#, wpf, scope

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, c# WPF.  I have created a `MediaElement` control during runtime;

```
MediaElement video= new MediaElement();
video.Width = 400;
video.Height = 400;
video.Play();

video.Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
```

In the XAML view I created 2 buttons, Play and Stop which I will show to be visible only if a mediaElement is created.  But I need to add click_events to these 2 buttons.  But when I write `video.Play();` it does not know this name.  Does anyone know how to get this name to be recognised in these seperate methods?

```
private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   video.Play();    //syntax error under video
}

private void stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   video.Play();    //syntax error under video
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `video` as a member variable. For example, say you're in a class called `MediaWindow`...

```
public class MediaWindow
{
    private MediaElement video = new MediaElement { Width = 400, Height = 400};

    public void SetVideoSource(string path)
    {
        video.Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
    }

    private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       video.Play();
    }

    private void stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       video.Stop(); 
    }
}
```

Adjust for your actual class structure and setup.